# How do i call the case function

Tags: shell

I have the following script to login to the servers. This scripts enables me to login to the host automatically using expect script based on the option i choose. As soon as i logout from the host im landing on my terminal.

I would require a help such that, once i logout from the server it should prompt to choose the options once again instead going out of the script.

```
PS3='Please enter your choice: '

select options in Testserver1 Testserver2 Quit

do

    case $options in

        "Testserver1")
            echo "you chose SOX DS's"
            DSS=Testserver1
            break
            ;;
        "Testserver2")
            DSS=Testserver2
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
           exit 0
           ;;
        *) echo invalid option
           exit
           ;;
    esac
done

        echo "$DSS"

expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no c1177243@$DSS \r\"; expect -re \"password:\"; send \"dummy@1233\n\"; expect -ex \"$\"; send \"sudo su - $env\n\"; expect \"c1177243\"; send \"dummy@1233\n\"; expect -ex \"$\"; send \"ls\r\"; expect -ex \"$\"; send \"cd splunk/etc/deployment-apps\r\"; interact"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your script in something like :

```
while true
do
  ... your script here
done
```

You already have an exit condition, so this should work. If it is not, please indicate how it is failing